# Double the digits in string and apply them

Tags: python, python-3.x

eg : `a = "452398" i want to take all the indices(one after - one after digits) like (4 , 2 , 9) double them == (8 , 4 , 18)

next step to check if the doubled digits is greater than 9 if so  need to subtract from 9 (8 , 4 , 9) and finally i want add the digits in a ("854398") it must a string any idea  how to do it ?

i tired for loop using range , len skip i sorted out everything till the last step but i couldn't apply the digits in "a" . so deleted the whole loop :(

Comment: Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`string` is immutable so first you should create a `list` of `characters` using your `string`

```
a = '452398'
new = list(a)
```

then create a `loop` to do your conditions and change the value of characters in the list

```
for i in range(0,len(new),2):
    num = int(new[i]) * 2
    if num  > 9:
        new[i] = num - 9
    else:
        new[i] = num
```

now overwrite the value of your variable `a` using your new list of characters.

```
a = ''.join(map(str,new))
```

Here is the whole code.

```
a = '452398'
new = list(a)
for i in range(0,len(new),2):
    num = int(new[i]) * 2
    if num  > 9:
        new[i] = num - 9
    else:
        new[i] = num

a = ''.join(map(str,new))

print(a)
```

Comment: check if the doubled digits is greater than 9 if so need to subtract from 9

Comment: i can understand that. But the code new[i] is confusing me can  you explain me it in a elegant way ? please

Answer (score 2):

This does what you described, but why would you want to do that:

```
a = "452398"
a_list = [int(x) for x in a]
numbers = [x*2 for x in a_list[::2]]
numbers = [x-9 if x>9 else x for x in numbers]
result = [j for i in zip(numbers,a_list[1::2]) for j in i]
result = map(str, result)
result = ''.join(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you do it using list comprehensions

```
A = "452398"
res = "".join([(str(min(int(a) * 2, 9)) if idx % 2 == 0 else a) for idx, a in enumerate(A)])
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the simple answers could be.

```
a = '452398'
b = []

for i, x in enumerate(a):
    if (i%2 == 0):
        res = int(x) * 2
        if len(str(res)) > 1:
            res = res - 9
        b.append(res)
    else:
        b.append(x)

b = map(str, b)
b = ''.join(b)
print(b)
```